# What's the most important factor for SSRS performance (Proc/Ram/IO)

Tags: sql-server, performance, reporting-services, virtual-machine

I'm building a new SSRS VM in Azure.

The VM will host all the application RDLs. Report execution will be done via webservice call from a cloud app. And the datasource for the reports will be a SQL Azure Database.

So really all the SSRS box is doing is co-ordinating the query-exec, converts to PDF and sends out the document via the web service response.

Each report is very simple (1 page PDF invoice, with a query to fetch a single row by PKID). but volume could be around ~2500 reports per hour.

All other things being equal, would I be better off going for a More Cores, More RAM or More IO (SSD based) Azure VM based on the above.

I'll have opportunity to spin up a couple of VMs in advance for R&D purposes to do some benchmarking but just wondering where the likely bottle necks are going to be.